# Why does reading real time output from Python 3 subprocess require pressing enter for data output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I have been reading through the available questions regarding real time processing of a subprocess in Python 3 though none of them address the exact issue I am experiencing. I am working on a script to parse relevant data and format the output of a Source Server specifically for Day of Infamy.

When the script starts, it launches the Day of Infamy server (./doi.sh) which gives server start up variables such as map, playlist, battle eye server data, etc.  At a certain point the server script is just hanging, waiting for an event such as a connection or a kill to take place.  At this point the server would log it to STDOUT, however my Python program stops outputting any data unless you press 'enter' key.  After pressing 'enter' the most recent event data is printed.

What could be causing the need to press enter for more output?  Could it be something times out when the doi.sh server script is waiting for an event?

My current code for running and reading from the subprocess is:

`cmd = './doi.sh'
data = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=1)`

while True:
        output = data.stdout.readline()
        if output == '' and data.poll() is not None:
                break
        if output:
                output = output.decode('utf-8')
                print(output)

I have functions built to parse the info from the decoded string, these work on the lines that are output by the subprocess, but having to press enter to update the console log defeats the purpose of the whole program.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly an issues with the buffering of stdout. Try replacing the command as like this:

```
stdbuf -o0 ./doi.sh
```

This will force the stdout for `doi.sh` to be unbuffered. You will also need to set the keyword arg `shell=True` in `subprocess.Popen()`

Here is a good explanation of this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Comment: Unfortunately it still hangs and waits for the enter key at the points mentioned.  I noticed that when shell=True was not set I need to send in a list of arguments ['stdbuf', '-o0', './doi.sh'].  However, when I set shell=True as a Popen arg, I could pass in a string 'stdbuf -o0 ./doi.sh'. Why is that?

Comment: Here is a pretty good explanation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments - TL;DR when shell is false, the input is a list of args, where arg[0] is the file name of the program to be executed. If you pass it a shell command, it would try and find a program with the whole string as its name, spaces automatically escaped. If shell is true, it passes the whole string along to a system shell to be interpreted.

Comment: If this isn't a problem when you run `./doi.sh` directly from a shell, perhaps it is expecting a tty. Worth a shot with `unbuffer ./doi.sh` (needs to be installed first), but if that doesn't work, it may come down to playing around with python's `pty` module